# How to convert arrayBuffer to JSON in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arraybuffer

I am using Axios and I am getting `arraybuffer` as a response. I want to convert `arraybuffer` to `json`. I really tried hard but didn't find a proper solution. Could someone please help me.

Thanks

```js
axios.post(
  `${config.apiPath}/api/generatepdf`,
  {
    onlyForPdf: 'pdf',
  },
  {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/pdf',
    },
  }
).then((res) => {
  console.log('2@ res', JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode([res.data])))
}
```

In console it returns undefined

Comment: It looks like you're requesting a PDF. How would you convert a PDF to JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Use the syntax below to switch back to JSON.

```
let arrayBufferConverted = JSON.parse(
 String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(res.data))
   )
```

Comment: I really doubt OP's `application/pdf` response can be parsed as JSON.

Comment: Thank you it working fine......